# SSIS Connections - Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: ssis

My issue is two fold and relates to simply creating a connection to databases (please understand this might be very basic, but as this is my first SSIS attempt, I am very confused on the basics).

We are doing our development on our servers with SQL Server and IS Installed, not from our local computer. When we access our servers, we need to use TPAM for all server access. As such, how do I configure a SQL Connection inside my SSIS project to connect to SQL Server using a predefined Windows Service Account (we cannot use SQL Logins for any database access, as all access must be granted via a domain service account).

I need this package to connect to Oracle and pull data into our SQL Server database. When I try and create an Oracle connection using "OracleClient Data Provider", I get an error stating "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. The problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed". Based on this error, I installed varous options from "winx64_12102_client", but still getting this error. What needs installed to connect to Oracle?

If I try to connect to Oracle using "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle", I get the following error "Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation". I did install various options from the above mentioned Oracle install, but this didn't seem to help.

Could anyone point me in a direction to get this working? Google did not help me with teh SQL Server connection, and I found a bunch of "stuff" based on the Oracle errors, but many items stating different "packages" that need installed and I do not want to start installing anything and everything related to Oracle on our servers, but only what is needed which doesn't seem to be what I ran.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the 1st error, try the following

1. Right click your SSIS Project, then click **Properties**.
2. Expand to the **Configuration Properties** -> **Debugging** and
3. Change the setting for **`Run64BitRuntime`** to `false`.
4. Click **OK** and try again.

[image]

If this fixes it, then you don't need to go down the other route you were going down.

Answer (score 0):

Shiva's Answer will not help you in the long run. Microsoft's (SQL Server's) Oracle provider is not supported by Oracle for quite some time now.

You will have to install Oracle's OLEDB Provider on your SQL Server. The following tutorial solved the problem for us: https://serverfault.com/a/175429/356277

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, but unfortunately the project property change did not solve the issue.  The end result was that I needed to install the 32-bit Oracle drivers, which required a registry hack I found here:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/3725625?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Well, maybe you should've taken a look at the link I posted. There is no hack necessary. Simply install Oracle's "Oracle Provider for OLEDB"